# NSMutableString is not appending, it's allways null

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablestring

I'm trying to set a NSMutablearray, but always get null value, it doesn't update with different values on the iterations. Here is the code:

```
NSMutableString *tipo = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];

        if (self.canas.on){
             [tipo stringByAppendingString: @"0"];   
        }

        if (self.copas.on){
            if ([tipo length]==0){
                 [tipo stringByAppendingString: @"1"];

            }else{
                [tipo stringByAppendingString:@",1"];
            }
        }

        if (self.comer.on){
            if ([tipo length]==0){
             [tipo stringByAppendingString: @"2"];

        }else{
            [tipo stringByAppendingString:@",2"];
            }
        }
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

Because you should use [`appendString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutablestring_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/appendString%3a) method, NOT [`stringByAppendingString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAppendingString%3a).

The difference is that the first does append the argument to the receiver while the second just returns such value (the receiver remains intact). The second message could be send to `NSString` while the first is only for `NSMutableString`.

Hope you see the difference.